# Find element by class name make the error: "Traceback (most recent call last)"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I logged in to Instagram and I'm trying to press a button to close a popup but every time get this no matter what I try, *I repleced the username and password only to put the code here..

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

path = "/Users/almogbenlulu/Desktop/Almog/python/chromedriver.exe"
s = Service(path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))

driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys("*****")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys("*****")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '_acan _acao _acas')))

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '_acan _acao _acas').click()

driver.quit()
```

And I always get this even without the wait for the element

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/almogbenlulu/Desktop/Almog/python/Automation/venv/day1/insta.py", line 22, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '_acan _acao _acas')))
  File "/Users/almogbenlulu/Desktop/Almog/python/Automation/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x00000001048052c8 chromedriver + 4752072
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000104785463 chromedriver + 4228195
2   chromedriver                        0x00000001043e8b18 chromedriver + 441112
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000104425e21 chromedriver + 691745
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000104426061 chromedriver + 692321
5   chromedriver                        0x00000001044615e4 chromedriver + 935396
6   chromedriver                        0x0000000104446d2d chromedriver + 826669
7   chromedriver                        0x000000010445f134 chromedriver + 926004
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000104446b33 chromedriver + 826163
9   chromedriver                        0x00000001044179fd chromedriver + 633341
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000104419051 chromedriver + 639057
11  chromedriver                        0x00000001047d230e chromedriver + 4543246
12  chromedriver                        0x00000001047d6a88 chromedriver + 4561544
13  chromedriver                        0x00000001047de6df chromedriver + 4593375
14  chromedriver                        0x00000001047d78fa chromedriver + 4565242
15  chromedriver                        0x00000001047ad2cf chromedriver + 4391631
16  chromedriver                        0x00000001047f65b8 chromedriver + 4691384
17  chromedriver                        0x00000001047f6739 chromedriver + 4691769
18  chromedriver                        0x000000010480c81e chromedriver + 4782110
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8188bd4e1 _pthread_start + 125
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8188b8f6b thread_start + 15

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is what I try to catch

```
<div class="_ac8f"><button class="_acan _acao _acas" type="button">Not Now</button></div>
```

Comment: if i try to execute your code, i have this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9f _ab9m _ab9p _abcm">...</div> is not clickable at point (389, 293). Other element would receive the click: <div class="_aacl _aaco _aacu _aacx _aad6">...</div>`

Comment: Well, it's a button you can see in the HTML

Answer (score 1):

`By.CLASS_NAME` receives single parameter value while `_acan _acao _acas` are 3 class names.
To locate element based on multiple class names you can use CSS Selector or XPath.
So, instead of

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '_acan _acao _acas')))
```

Try using

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._acan._acao._acas')))
```

Also, the above line returns web element. So, to click it you do not need to locate it again with `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '_acan _acao _acas').click()`
This will do it:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._acan._acao._acas'))).click()
```

Comment: driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/tosha_bakery/?next=%2F")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_uv"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section/main/div/header/section/div[3]/a[2]/span/div/span[3]')))
num_of_mutuals = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_uv"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section/main/div/header/section/div[3]/a[2]/span/div/span[3]')
mutuals = num_of_mutuals[0]
print(mutuals)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 25, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_uv"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section/main/div/header/section/div[3]/a[2]/span/div/span[3]')))
  File "/Users/almogbenlulu/Desktop/Almog/python/Automation/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Now I get this error

Comment: 1) This is a new issue 2) You have to learn to create correct locators, not to use these absolute XPaths

Comment: You're right I know but every time I use the Class name it doesn't work,
Can you show me how would you catch the class name here of the third row where "+ 38 more" please?

<div class="_aacl _aacn _aacv _aacy _aad6">Followed by <span class="_aaai">yuval_nagar258</span>, <span class="_aaai">maor__eliezer</span>, <span class="_aaai">shani.cn</span> + 38 more</div>

Comment: Probably you will need to use some other locator type, not by class name but by XPath or by CSS Selector while making the locator unique and fixed based on some parent element